# Set QGraphicBlurEffect to QStackWidget without affecting widgets in it

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, pyside2

I'm trying to set blur to the background of a QStackWidget. Main window is set to be transparent and the stack widget is made semi-transparent with style sheet. When I try to blur the stack widget, it blurs everything in it. How do I blur only stack widget background without blurring out the widgets in it?

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
from PySide2.QtCore import *

li = ["item1", "item2"]


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        self.resize(500, 400)

        self.label = QLabel("Noting to see here")

        self.tab1 = QLabel("You can't see me")
        self.tab1.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.tab2 = QLabel("Now you can")
        self.tab2.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.tab3 = QLabel("Now you don't")
        self.tab3.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.tabWidget = QTabWidget()
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab1, "t1")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab2, "t2")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab3, "t2")
        self.tabWidget.setTabPosition(QTabWidget.West)

        self.Blur = QGraphicsBlurEffect()
        self.tabWidget.tabBar().setGraphicsEffect(self.Blur)

        self.tabWidget.setStyleSheet("QTabWidget{background: none;"
                                     "border:  0px;"
                                     "margin: 0px;"
                                     "padding: 0px;}"
                                     "QTabBar:tab{background: rgba(0, 200, 220, 20);}"
                                     "QTabBar:tab:hover{background: rgba(200, 200, 200, 120);}"
                                     "QTabBar:tab:selected{background: rgb(0, 150, 220);}")

        self.sw = QStackedWidget()
        self.sw.addWidget(self.label)
        self.sw.addWidget(self.tabWidget)
        self.sw.setStyleSheet("background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 10);")

        if li is None:
            self.sw.setCurrentWidget(self.label)

        else:
            self.sw.setCurrentWidget(self.tabWidget)

        self.toolBar = QToolBar()
        self.toolBar.setFixedHeight(30)
        self.toolBar.setStyleSheet("background: grey;")

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.setSpacing(0)
        self.layout.setMargin(0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.toolBar)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.sw)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Simply put, I want blur like in the image.

[image: blur background]

[image]

Comment: If you apply a graphics effect to a widget it is applied to all of its children, but, on the other hand, a QStackedWidget has practically no content, so applying a blur effect to it alone wouldn't have any effect if not on its children. Anyway, I'm afraid that what you want to achieve is to make the effect blur what's "behind" the widget through its transparency. If that's what you want, you can't: the blur effect is only applied to what Qt "paints" on its own, not on what's beyond the windows.

Comment: I've updated the question just to clarify things. Any insights/help appreciated.

Comment: So, you want to blur the "desktop background" (as in, what appears in the transparency). As said, it's not possible: Qt does not have access to what's "beyond" its windows, it only paints its widgets using an alpha channel when the transparency flag is set, and it's up to the window system of the OS to "composite" everything you see.

Comment: Not the desktop background, but the backgrounds of the tabs and the stack widget without blurring out whats in it.

Comment: The background of the tabs *is* what's behind the window (in this case, apparently, the desktop, but it could be any foreign window).

Comment: I've updated the question again for more clarity.

Comment: Sorry but I really don't understand you. What part should be "blurred"? Do you want the tab border to be blurred, while keeping the tab contents (text and icon) normal? If that's so, it's not possible. Otherwise, please upload a more precise image of what you *want*, not of what you don't, possibly with a sharper background so that the result would be more clear.

Comment: "Do you want the tab border to be blurred, while keeping the tab contents (text and icon) normal? If that's so, it's not possible." This is the closest answer to my question.

Comment: Image updated for clarity

Comment: From what I can see, the only blurred parts are *not* the tab borders, but the tab widget *background* (aka, the desktop or the content of other windows "under" yours). If that's what you want, I already told you that you cannot do it.

Comment: I've added new image. I want to achieve something like in the image, blur background, not what's behind the window.

Comment: That IS exactly what blurring behind the window means. And, for the last time, you can **not** do it from Qt.

Comment: The question was simple, blur a widget without blurring widgets in it. There is some miscommunications here.

Comment: There's no misunderstanding, what you've shown in the last image you uploaded is *not* directly possible from Qt. It might be possible on Windows using [QtWin](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwin.html) `enableBlurBehindWindow`, but that has to be set to the top level window, it's not cross platform, it has nothing to do with QGraphicsBlurEffect and there's no control over it (you can just enable/disable it, and it only works if the hw/sw configuration allows it).